# What was C.F Gauss's work on the problem of the volume of tetrahedron in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: biographical-details

My question is a continuation of this posted question: [Why did Gauss recommend Janos Bolyai to find the volume of a tetrahedron in hyperbolic geometry?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/why-did-gauss-recommend-janos-bolyai-to-find-the-volume-of-a-tetrahedron-in-hype?rq=1). The issue is that since i asked the previous question i found additional material in Gauss's works - i think the relevant note in Gauss's nachlass is in page 228 of volume 8 of his  work - http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN236010751|LOG_0072&physid=PHYS_0234. It's a little note entitled "CUBIRUNG DER TETRAEDER".  it seems to me like an important note since Stackel carefullty comments on it. So can anyone tell something about that?

Comment: Peter Heinig - i ask you to help me on this question after you helped me a lot and wrote a great post on the question i asked about the topological ideas that Gauss introduced to mobius. I ask you because you know to read german. Of course you don't have to make such great efforts again - i just ask for a translation of the note "cubirung der tetraeder" (Gauss's werke, volume 8, page 228-232) and Stackel's commentary on it.

Comment: @Peter Heinig - i ask you to help me on this question after you helped me a lot and wrote a great post on the question i asked about the topological ideas that Gauss introduced to mobius. I ask you because you know to read german. Of course you don't have to make such great efforts again - i just ask for a translation of the note "cubirung der tetraeder" (Gauss's werke, volume 8, page 228-232) and Stackel's commentary on it.